# How to enable OpenSSL for c++ sleepy-discord

Tags: c++, openssl

I have to use c++ for a discord bot and I want to use the library sleepy-discord but I don't know how to fix this Error. I think I have to import OpenSSL in the CMake file but I don't know how either.

My CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(TestProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(TestProject main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(deps/sleepy-discord)
target_link_libraries(TestProject sleepy-discord)
```

Error:

```
-- curl version=[7.56.0-DEV]
Found *nroff option: -- -man
CMake Error at deps/sleepy-discord/deps/cpr/opt/curl/CMakeLists.txt:693 (message):
  CA path only supported by OpenSSL, GnuTLS or mbed TLS.  Set
  CURL_CA_PATH=none or enable one of those TLS backends.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Linux, if so please install libcurl-openssl-dev from your package manager.

Comment: Hey thanks for the Answer! I'm using MacOS and I solved it, with adding a flag to the location of my openssl lib: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-I /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include/")